# UIPageViewController OR UIScrollView with Paging Enabled = YES

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiscrollview, uipagecontrol

I've gotten a little confused for how I should implement below,

I need to **scroll between UIViews or UIViewControllers** each one having different set of data do display. For example, 1st view has a UITableView, other only has a button, 3rd may again have a UITableView.

Should I be using **UIPageViewController and load different UIViewControllers** for each content OR use **UIScrollView with contentSize = number of pages**.

In my current implementation. I have used UIScrollView which scrolls between different UIViews and loads their content. But, the problem is when I tap on the UITableView in one of the views, tap events are not captured by UITableView, but UIScrollView captures the touch events.

I did try bringing my UITableView to front with,

```
 myTable.becomeFirstResponder()
 scrollView.bringSubviewToFront(myTable)

 scrollView.delaysContentTouches = false
 scrollView.canCancelContentTouches = false
```

I added a UITapGestureRecognizer on UITableView but it does not receive tap events. UIScrollView receives a tap event if I add UITapGestureRecognizer on it.

My current view heirarchy is,

```
UIScrollView -->
              UIView --> 
                       UITableView
              UIView -->
                       UIButton and other subViews
              UIView --> 
                       UITableView
```

NOTE : I want this scroll view or paging view only as a portion of my main View Controller. (half of my main view)

Please guide me through this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution myself,

I just had to remove the UIView from the hierarchy where a UITableView was required.
So now my view hierarchy becomes,

```
UIScrollView -->

          UITableView --> 

          UIView -->
                   UIButton and other subViews
          UITableView -->
```